# What is the best way to read multiple files into one?

Tags: file, memory-management, rust, io, buffer

Here's a benchmark comparing two functions that read multiple files into a single one. The one uses `read` and the other uses `read_to_end`. My original motivation was to get the buffer's `capacity` be equal to the `len` at the end of the process. This did not happen with `read_to_end` which was quite unsatisfactory.

With `read` however, this works. The `assert_eq!(buf.capacity(), buf.len());` of `read_files_into_file2` (which uses `read`) does not panic.

```rs
use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::{
    fs,
    io::{self, Seek},
};

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut files = get_test_files().unwrap();

    let mut file = fs::File::create("output").unwrap();

    c.bench_function("1", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            read_files_into_file1(&mut files, &mut file).unwrap();
        })
    });

    c.bench_function("2", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            read_files_into_file2(&mut files, &mut file).unwrap();
        });
    });
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);

/// Goes back to the start so that the files can be read again from the start.
fn reset(files: &mut Vec<fs::File>, file: &mut fs::File) {
    file.seek(io::SeekFrom::Start(0)).unwrap();
    for file in files {
        file.seek(io::SeekFrom::Start(0)).unwrap();
    }
}

pub fn read_files_into_file1(files: &mut Vec<fs::File>, file: &mut fs::File) -> io::Result<()> {
    reset(files, file);

    let total_len = files
        .iter()
        .map(|file| file.metadata().unwrap().len())
        .sum::<u64>() as usize;
    let mut buf = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(total_len);

    for file in files {
        file.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
    }

    file.write_all(&buf)?;

    // assert_eq!(buf.capacity(), buf.len());

    Ok(())
}

fn read_files_into_file2(files: &mut Vec<fs::File>, file: &mut fs::File) -> io::Result<()> {
    reset(files, file);

    let total_len = files
        .iter()
        .map(|file| file.metadata().unwrap().len())
        .sum::<u64>() as usize;
    let mut vec: Vec<u8> = vec![0; total_len];
    let mut buf = &mut vec[..];

    for file in files {
        match file.read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(n) => {
                buf = &mut buf[n..];
            }
            Err(err) if err.kind() == io::ErrorKind::Interrupted => {}
            Err(err) => return Err(err),
        }
    }

    file.write_all(&vec)?;

    // assert_eq!(vec.capacity(), vec.len());

    Ok(())
}

/// Creates 5 files with content "hello world" 500 times.
fn get_test_files() -> io::Result<Vec<fs::File>> {
    let mut files = Vec::<fs::File>::new();

    for index in 0..5 {
        let mut file = fs::OpenOptions::new()
            .read(true)
            .write(true)
            .truncate(true)
            .create(true)
            .open(&format!("test{}", index))?;

        file.write_all("hello world".repeat(500).as_bytes())?;

        files.push(file);
    }

    Ok(files)
}
```

If you uncomment the `assert_eq!`s then you will see that only `read_files_into_file1` (which uses `read_to_end`) fails with this panic:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `55000`,
 right: `27500`', benches/bench.rs:53:5
```

`read_files_into_file1` allocates way more memory than needed while `read_files_into_file2` allocates the optimal amount.

Despite that, the results say that they perform almost the same (`read_files_into_file1` takes 11.439 us and `read_files_into_file2` takes 11.098 us):

```
1                       time:   [11.417 us 11.439 us 11.463 us]               
                        change: [+3.7987% +3.9997% +4.1984%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has regressed.
Found 1 outliers among 100 measurements (1.00%)
  1 (1.00%) high mild

2                       time:   [11.085 us 11.098 us 11.112 us]               
                        change: [+0.1255% +0.5081% +0.9545%] (p = 0.01 < 0.05)
                        Change within noise threshold.
Found 4 outliers among 100 measurements (4.00%)
  2 (2.00%) high mild
  2 (2.00%) high severe
```

I expect `read_files_into_file2` to be much faster but it was even shown to be slower when I increased the file size. Why is it that `read_files_into_file2` does not meet my expectations and what is the best way to read multiple files into one, efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

`read_to_end` generally isn't a good idea when dealing with large files since it will try to read the whole file into memory which can lead to swapping or out of memory errors.

On linux and assuming single-threaded execution using `io::copy` should be the fastest method since it contains [optimizations for this case](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/75272).

On other platforms using `io::copy` and wrapping the writer side in a BufWriter [lets you control the buffer size](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/78641) used for copying which will help amortizing syscall costs.

If you can use multiple threads and know that the file lengths don't change then you can use platform-specific positional read/write methods such as [read_at](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.FileExt.html#tymethod.read_at) to read multiple files in parallel and write the data into the correct places in the destination file. Whether this actually provides a speedup depends on many factors. It's probably most beneficial when concatenating many small files from a network filesystem.

Beyond the standard library there also are crates that expose platform-specific copy routines which may be faster than a naive userspace copy approach.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about `io::copy`. I have updated the benchmark with two new functions based on your suggestions: `read_files_into_file3` and `read_files_into_file4`. Unfortunately if I run the benchmark, `read_to_end` and `read` are still on top and the functions using `io::copy` are shown to be the slowest, so I must be doing something wrong. Please take a look at the functions here: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/8803145e40494a09a207e3af76adf3ed

Comment: `read_files_into_file3` still uses an intermediate vec instead of using `io::copy` to go straight from file to file. And your files are really tiny (a few kilobytes each). Syscall overhead probably dominates at those sizes. Optimizing for many small files is different from optimizing for throughput on large files.

Comment: `read_files_into_file4` also does something unnecessary, it queries the size of each file to construct a `BufWriter`. The point of using a bufwriter generally is to have a fixed-sized buffer that amortizes write costs, it doesn't need to know the exact size for that. It just needs to be big enough so that the time spent copying bytes dominates compared to the syscall overhead.

Comment: @the8472 I can't add much to the issue at hand, but I think its important to note that most important factor in whether this can be parallelized is underlying hardware. Using multiple threads for IO on HDD isn't good while on SSD would almost always provide a speedup for big enough files.

Comment: I added two new functions: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/80dfcae885bb40f3b457b3d2003d485b (results below). For a size of `"hello world".repeat(10000)` the direct copying variant without a buffer is the fastest. For smaller sizes like `"a".repeat(2_usize.pow(10))`, `read_to_end` and `read` still dominate. I think I should use multiple solutions depending on the size. Is there a recommendation for a big enough size where I do `io::copy` + no buffer or else `read_to_end`? Should it be a power of 2? Also, I still don't understand why `read_to_end` could be faster than `read`. Why could that be?

Comment: If you want to know what exactly takes time you'll need to analyze with `perf`, `strace` or similar performance tracing tools that show which syscalls happen and where the time is spent in the operating system. For small files the syscall overhead probably dominates compared to the IO time or the time spent copying bytes. For large files using efficient methods that the operating system can optimize matters more.